# Error loading (xmonad) modules in GHCi within a stack deployment of xmonad for development

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, xmonad

I am trying to develop a ManageHook for XMonad, and have deployed a development
environment in the following way (as described [here](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-testing)).

In my `~/.xmonad/` I have a working `xmonad.hs`. I have also added there
an `~/.xmonad/src/` subdir with git checkouts of the xmonad, xmonad-contrib, and
X11 packages.  And also there in  `~/.xmonad/` I have an
`xmonad-testing.cabal`, `stack.yaml`, and `build` files, with contents:

xmonad-testing.cabal:

```
name:          xmonad-testing
version:       0.13
-- [ ... more metadata ... ]
build-type:    Simple
cabal-version: >=1.8

executable xmonad-testing
  main-is: xmonad.hs
  ghc-options: -Wall -fno-warn-missing-signatures
  build-depends: base, containers, X11, xmonad, xmonad-contrib
```

stack.yaml:

```
resolver: lts-9.6

packages:
- .
- src/xmonad
- src/xmonad-contrib
- src/X11

extra-deps:
- X11-xft-0.3.1
- directory-1.2.7.1
- xmobar-0.24.3
```

build:

```
SRC_DIR=~/.xmonad

EXE_NAME=xmonad-testing

output_file=$1; shift

cd $SRC_DIR
stack build
stack install
DIR=`stack path --local-bin`/$EXE_NAME
mv -u $DIR $output_file
```

With this files in place, I can `cd ~/.xmonad/`, and then run `stack setup &&
stack build && stack install && xmonad-testing --recompile`, and then I
can call the xmonad executable from `~/.xinitrc` like
`exec ~/.xmonad/xmonad-x86_64-linux`, and all goes well, no problem with this, I can edit the
sources in `~/.xmonad/src/` and load the changes with mod4Mask-Q.

However, when I execute, in `~/.xmonad/`, `stack ghci`, I obtain a couple
of errors before getting the ghci prompt:

errors from "stack ghci":

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Layout/LayoutCombinators.hs:178:0: error:
     error: unterminated comment
     (*/**)     = combineTwo (Mirror $ Tall 1 0.1 (1/3))

`gcc' failed in phase `C pre-processor'. (Exit code: 1)

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Graphics.X11’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘X11-1.8@X11-1.8-9LIA1IrKR3LITr8rHkiWyN’.
```

And then I try to load some module (e.g. XMonad.Actions.TreeSelect) with: `:l XMonad.Actions.TreeSelect`
and I get a bunch of errors and the module never loads - a module that
is actually working in the running X session. What may be the problem? I
end the post with the errors trying to load the module in ghci:

errors loading xmonad-contrib module in ghci:

```
Prelude> :l XMonad.Actions.TreeSelect

  [    ......     ]
  [ MANY WARNINGS ]
  [    ......     ]


/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:117:37: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘xftFontOpen’, namely ‘dpy’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘xftFontOpen
           dpy (defaultScreenOfDisplay dpy) (drop (length xftPrefix) s)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        xftdraw <- io
                   $ xftFontOpen
                       dpy (defaultScreenOfDisplay dpy) (drop (length xftPrefix) s)

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:117:42: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Screen’
                  with actual type ‘Screen’
      NB: ‘Screen’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(55,1)-(57,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Screen’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the second argument of ‘xftFontOpen’, namely
        ‘(defaultScreenOfDisplay dpy)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘xftFontOpen
           dpy (defaultScreenOfDisplay dpy) (drop (length xftPrefix) s)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        xftdraw <- io
                   $ xftFontOpen
                       dpy (defaultScreenOfDisplay dpy) (drop (length xftPrefix) s)

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:130:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘xftFontClose’, namely ‘dpy’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘xftFontClose dpy xftfont’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: io $ xftFontClose dpy xftfont

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:141:26: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘xftTextExtents’, namely ‘dpy’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: gi <- xftTextExtents dpy xftdraw s
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘do { gi <- xftTextExtents dpy xftdraw s;
              return $ xglyphinfo_xOff gi }’

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:199:29: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘xftTextExtents’, namely ‘dpy’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘xftTextExtents dpy font s’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: gi <- io $ xftTextExtents dpy font s

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:205:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘withXftDraw’, namely ‘dpy’
      In the expression: withXftDraw dpy drw visual colormap
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘withXftDraw dpy drw visual colormap
         $ \ draw
             -> withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
                $ \ color -> xftDrawString draw color font x y s’

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:205:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Visual’
                  with actual type ‘Visual’
      NB: ‘Visual’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(63,1)-(65,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Visual’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the third argument of ‘withXftDraw’, namely ‘visual’
      In the expression: withXftDraw dpy drw visual colormap
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘withXftDraw dpy drw visual colormap
         $ \ draw
             -> withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
                $ \ color -> xftDrawString draw color font x y s’

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:206:36: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
                  with actual type ‘Display’
      NB: ‘Display’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(47,1)-(49,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Display’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the first argument of ‘withXftColorName’, namely ‘dpy’
      In the expression: withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
      In the expression:
        withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
        $ \ color -> xftDrawString draw color font x y s

/home/eperez/src/git/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/XMonad/Util/Font.hs:206:40: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Visual’
                  with actual type ‘Visual’
      NB: ‘Visual’ is defined at
            Graphics/X11/Xlib/Types.hsc:(63,1)-(65,48)
          ‘X11-1.8:Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types.Visual’
            is defined in ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types’ in package ‘X11-1.8’
    • In the second argument of ‘withXftColorName’, namely ‘visual’
      In the expression: withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
      In the expression:
        withXftColorName dpy visual colormap fc
        $ \ color -> xftDrawString draw color font x y s
Failed, modules loaded: Graphics.X11, Graphics.X11.Types, Graphics.X11.Xinerama, Graphics.X11.Xlib, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Atom, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Color, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Context, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Cursor, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Display, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Event, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Font, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Image, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Internal, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Misc, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Region, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Screen, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types, Graphics.X11.Xlib.Window, Graphics.X11.Xrandr, Paths_xmonad, XMonad, XMonad.Config, XMonad.Core, XMonad.Hooks.WorkspaceHistory, XMonad.Layout, XMonad.Main, XMonad.ManageHook, XMonad.Operations, XMonad.StackSet, XMonad.Util.ExtensibleState, XMonad.Util.TreeZipper.
*XMonad.Hooks.WorkspaceHistory>
```

---

**Edited to add**:

This is not a solution, but rather a workaround: if I run `stack exec -- ghci` rather than `stack ghci`, I have no problems loading whatever modules.

Comment: Did you configure the x11 package?

Comment: @Chris Stryczynski I'm not sure what you mean with configuring the x11 package - you mean in stack?

Comment: It's mentioned in the github repo readme

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski As I understand it, the configure step is only needed when you build manually, not when you use cabal  or stack. Do you disagree?